# split by regex except

Tags: python

```
import re
digit_count=0
number_count = 0
numbers = []
count=0

with open ("letters_and_numbers.txt") as f:
  for line in f.readlines():
    sub_strs = line.rstrip().split("-")
    file_words = re.split(r"[a-zA-Z\W]",line.rstrip())
    for word in file_words:
      if word.isdigit():
        digit_count += len(word)
        number_count += 1
        numbers.append(word)        
        foundNeg=False
        for i in range(1, len(sub_strs)):
          if str(sub_strs).startswith(word):
            foundNeg == True
            count-=int(word)
          else:
            foundNeg==False
            count+=int(word)

print "digits:",digit_count
print "amount of numbers:",number_count
print "numbers:",numbers
print "total:",count
```

I am trying to get the above program to work but it only can if i can split by regex whitespaces except negative signs.How do I fix it???

NEVER MIND I FIGURED IT OUT

Comment: Great you figured it out yourself. However leaving your question like this isn't helpful for others. If you think your question will be looked up and is helpful to others in the future then create your own answer to your question here. If that's not the case then I suggest you remove your question again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my answer.It is the code I used and it worked even when there were no spaces between numbers and letters.

```
import re
digit_count=0
number_count = 0
numbers = []
count=0

with open ("letters_and_numbers.txt") as f:
  for line in f.readlines():
    sub_strs = line.rstrip().split("-")
    for i in range(0, len(sub_strs)):
      file_words = re.split(r"[a-zA-Z\W]",sub_strs[i])
      for word in file_words:
        if word.isdigit():
          digit_count += len(word)
          number_count += 1
          if i >=1 and sub_strs[i].startswith(word):
            count-=int(word)
            digit_count+=1
            numbers.append("-")
            numbers.append(word)
          else:
            count+=int(word)
            numbers.append(word)

print "digits:",digit_count
print "amount of numbers:",number_count
print "numbers:",numbers
print "total:",count
```